# Connecting to MS SQL Server with Windows Authentication using Python?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc, windows-authentication, pyodbc

How do I connect MS SQL Server using Windows Authentication, with the pyodbc library?

I can connect via MS Access and SQL Server Management Studio, but cannot get a working connection ODBC string for Python.

Here's what I've tried (also without `'Trusted_Connection=yes'`):

```
pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes',
               driver='{SQL Server}', server='[system_name]',
               database='[databasename]')

pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', uid='me',
               driver='{SQL Server}', server='localhost',
               database='[databasename]')

pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes',
               driver='{SQL Server}', server='localhost',
               uid='me', pwd='[windows_pass]', database='[database_name]')

pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes',
               driver='{SQL Server}', server='localhost',
               database='[server_name]\\[database_name]')

pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes',
               driver='{SQL Server}', server='localhost',
               database='[server_name]\[database_name]')

pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes',
               driver='{SQL Server}',
               database='[server_name]\[database_name]')
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can specify the connection string as one long string that uses semi-colons (`;`) as the argument separator.

Working example:

```python
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver=SQL Server;Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT LastName FROM myContacts")
while 1:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break
    print(row.LastName)
cnxn.close()
```

For connection strings with lots of parameters, the following will accomplish the same thing but in a somewhat more readable way:

```python
conn_str = (
    r'Driver=SQL Server;'
    r'Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;'
    r'Database=myDB;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

(Note that there are no commas between the individual string components.)

Comment: Thanks, that `.\ ` syntax did the trick. Note that: `pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver='{SQL Server}', server='.\[server_name]', database='[database_name]')` also worked.

Comment: how to connect with userid and password

Comment: This did no work for me. The comment below worked though.

Comment: is there any way to pass a different set of windows auth credentials? e.g. 'Trusted_Connection=yes;UID=blah;PWD=blah'?

Comment: @mdegges - Not as such; Microsoft's ODBC driver treats `Trusted_Connection` and `UID`/`PWD` as mutually exclusive. The "preferred" solution on Windows clients would be to run the app as the other user via [runas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.11).aspx) (command line) or [Shift-Right_click] > "Run as different user" (GUI). The corresponding workaround on Linux would be to use the FreeTDS ODBC driver which still supports the older NTLM authentication scheme via the `DOMAIN=` connection string parameter.

Answer (score 28):

Windows Authentication can also be specified using a keyword. Nothing functionally different from the accepted answer, I think it makes code formatting a bit easier:

```
cnxn = connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='localhost', database='test',               
               trusted_connection='yes')
```

Comment: You mention a keyword, yet your string is not using it?

Comment: `trusted_connection` is the authentication-related keyword

Answer (score 9):

Just wanted to add something as I see the solutions here using localhost; in my experience, SQL Server has issues with this, not sure if its the ODBC driver or the service itse, and prefers the use of (local) if you don't want to specify the local machines name.

```
cnxn = connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='(local)', database='test',               
               trusted_connection='yes')
```

Comment: This needs to be higher. `localhost` didn't work for me. `(local)` did.

Comment: This works for me because I forgot my password and wanted to use windows authentication. Connected successfully from Jupyter Notebook to local sql server