# Connecting from Python to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to connect from IPython notebook to a SQL-Server database via integrated security.

Is this possible? I'm guessing yes it is.

How do I format the connection string in the following?

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql as psql
sql = "SELECT * FROM WHdb.dbo.vw_smallTable"
cnx = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=WHdb;Data Source=OurServerName"
data = psql.read_sql(sql, cnx)
```

This just gives an error.
Am I going about the `cnx` incorrectly?

Comment: Please post the full error

Comment: @IanAuld had to step away from the work machine (to sleep!) - I'll add the msg tomorrow. On the face of it does it look ok? Am I correct using a string in that way as the second argument of `read_sql`?

Comment: I doubt I'll be much help as I've never used SQLServer with Python. However this question as written falls squarely in to the "What isn't this code working?" close reason. I won't vote to close but it does run the risk of being closed as is

Comment: @IanAuld I hope this helps me - will try tomorrow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515420/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-using-python

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install the package, pypyodbc

```
!pip install pypyodbc
```

Then, you can import it as follows:

```
import pypyodbc as podbc
```

You can now create the connection:

```
conn = podbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=<YourServer>;Database=<YourDatabase>;uid=<YourUserName>;pwd=<YourPassword>"
```

Finally, you fetch your data as follows:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM WHdb.dbo.vw_smallTable"
cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchone()
while data:
    print(str(data[0]) + ", " + ... + ", " + str(data[n-1]))
    data = cursor.fetchone()
conn.close()
```

Note that n = number of columns in your table.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me well...

```
import pyodbc

server = 'myserver'

database = 'mydb'

username = 'myusername'

password = 'mypassword'



#Connection String

connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

cursor = connection.cursor()



#Sample select query

cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;")

row = cursor.fetchone()

while row:

    print row[0]

    row = cursor.fetchone()
```