# How to connect to Local MS SQL Express Edition using Python 3

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I am trying to connect to local MS SQL Express Edition. I am using `canopy` for Python editing.

Code:

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(server='******\SQLEXPRESS',user = 'MEA\*****',password='*****',database='BSEG')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Table')
print(cursor.fetchone())

conn.close()
```

Error::

> pymssql.pyx in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10734)()
>
> _mssql.pyx in _mssql.connect (_mssql.c:21821)()
>
> _mssql.pyx in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.**init** (_mssql.c:5917)()
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `user = 'MEA\*****',password='*****'`

`MEA\*****` seems to be `Windows login`, in this case you shouldn't pass in any password, your user name is enough, but you also should use `Integrated security` or `Trusted` parameter in your connection string

It should be smth like this:

```
server='******\SQLEXPRESS',Trusted_Connection=yes,database='BSEG'
```

Comment: Yes I am using windows login. Could you please provide me with the proper connection string.

Comment: I updated the answer, also, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515420/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-using-python

Answer (score 0):

In my local machine I only have the sql express instance, then after some tryes I get that server can be just ".". the user that I am using is sa