# SQL Server Connection - ERROR - Server Closed the Connection Unexpectedly

Tags: sql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I have the following code:

`import psycopg2
conn_string = "dbname=ASCTP, user=TNET\user, password=password, host=ADHMSI-AR-5P, port=1433, sslmode=require"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)`

I'm getting this error:
**OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.**

That's all that I'm running in the cell. I'm wondering if there is something more that I need to add in order to keep this connection. Do I need an additional argument? I have my actual SQL SELECT statement in a following cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned psycopg2 and used this code.

```
conn_str = (
    r'Driver={SQL Server};'
    r'Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;'
    r'Database=myDB;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

I found this code on another Stack Overflow [board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515420/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-using-python). I didn't figure out what the problem was, but at least I successfully connected.