# pyodbc - Unable to login using trusted connection

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc, windows-authentication

I am able to login to SQL Server in SSMS using Windows authentication.

{Image removed due to exposure of real email address}

But when I try the same using `pyodbc` it fails:

```
import pyodbc

cnxn_str = (
    r'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
    r'SERVER=.\SQLEXPRESS02;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    r'DATABASE=Scenario2025Max_Release 5.0_0523586A6813B825D031545D6E25A815;'
)

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 30, in 
> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', '[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\XXXXXXXX@outlook.com'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Scenario2025Max_Release 5.0_0523586A6813B825D031545D6E25A815" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\XXXXXXXXAccount@domain.com'. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Scenario2025Max_Release 5.0_0523586A6813B825D031545D6E25A815" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060)')

How is this possible?

UPDATE -
Added SQL Server logs for the error run -
[image]

Comment: Is you database ***really*** called `Scenario2025Max_Release 5.0_0523586A6813B825D031545D6E25A815`? With respect, that's a terrible name for a database.

Comment: Unfortunately its a system generated database name.

Comment: Have a look at the SQL Server's logs and get the *real* connection error. If you don't understand it, then [edit] your question and add that error to the question (and this time if it contains PII ***don't*** expose said PII).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "real connection error". I have posted the pyodbc connection message above. There is no connection error when I try connecting through SSMS.

Comment: That's not the true authentication error... Authentication errors returned from SQL Server are explicitly vague on purpose. Get the ones from the logs.

Comment: @RohanBapat, common reasons for the "cannot open database" error during login is the user account (MicrosoftAccount\XXXXXXXX@outlook.com) has not been added as a user to the database or the database does not exist or is unavailable for some reason.

Comment: In SSMS look at "SQL Server Logs" under "Management" in the Object Explorer

Comment: I have added the SQL Server logs from the run. Also the user account has been added to the database. I can access the database from SSMS using Windows Authentication, but not using pyodbc

Comment: We need the line from the logs that actually reports the error

Comment: Those logs aren't helpful, they don't contain the authentication error(s), and don't post images of code/errors

Comment: @RohanBapat, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515420/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-using-python/16515836) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I went through at least a hundred web pages over 2 full days on this, tried everything that was posted on StackOverflow threads, SQL/pyodbc/connectionsstrings blogs - restarting SQL Server, restarting my computer, modifying connection strings, changing SQL Server user permissions, but nothing worked.

Ultimately, I re-installed SQL Server entirely and I don't get the login failed error anymore, at least for now.